# Cannot make Python list copies to work

Tags: python

I have a problem when I try to work with a list and a copy of it. I know that there are certain ways to copy a list in Python and I think that I follow them. Here is my problem.

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append([0]*10)

b = a[:]

for j in a:
    j[0] = 1

print a
print b
```

I create a blank list. Then I add 10 sublists of zeros ([0,0,0,0,0....]). Then I copy the list and finally I iterate through the first one. But when I print them, both lists have been changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only created a *shallow* copy. This creates a new list with *references to the contained values*. The lists *contained* in `a` are still being shared between the lists `a` and `b`.

You can add a level of copying:

```
b = [elem[:] for elem in a]
```

This creates a new list object, containing shallow copies of the nested lists from `a`. Since the nested lists themselves contain immutable objects only (integers) this is enough here.

Or you can use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to have a library function do this for you, creating a copy by recursing over your structure and creating copies of anything mutable.

Answer (score 2):

To make a proper copy use `copy` module

```
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of creating a deep copy is to use the `copy.deepcopy` function of the `copy` module: [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 2):

3 options:

- Use the built in [list()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) function combined with a generator

`b = list(list(item) for item in a)`

- List comprehension

`b = [item[:] for item in a]`

- generic [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

`import copy
 b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: b = [item for item in a] doesn't seem to work while b = [item[:] for item in a]--as suggested in the answer below--does (with python 2.7)

Comment: ah, sorry, yes, really must read the question properly, need to copy the lists within the lists, rather than just copy the list, updated